# How do you query by a time delta with Ecto?

Tags: elixir, ecto

Trying to compose a query (finding all users created more than 30 days ago) that corresponds to the following psql query:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE date_part('day', now()-inserted_at) > 30;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from u in User, where: u.inserted_at > ago(30, "days")
```

https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#ago/2